# How to reverse the order of multiline text sections separated by blank newlines/line breaks?

Tags: command-line, text-editors, text-editing, ordering

How to reverse the order of multiline text sections separated by blank newlines/line breaks...

..., with a simple command or application, preferably without programming?

I don't want a sort, but a reverse order of the text sections only.

For example:

```
A
B

0
1

X
YX
Y

HTTP
FTP
```

becomes

```
HTTP
FTP

X
YX
Y

0
1

A
B
```

Comment: Sorry that I haven't accepted any answers yet. I have been away for awhile. I accepted peth's solution because it is the simplest. I upvoted all working solutions. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tac` accepts a separator, so in e.g. `bash` you can do:

```
tac -s $'\n\n' foo
```

which will produce slightly incorrect output because the last paragraph isn't terminated by a double newline. So,

```
(cat foo; echo) | tac -s $'\n\n' | sed '$d'
```

is probably what you'd want. (Pipe contents of `foo` and newline through `tac`, then `sed` to strip the last line.)

**Note:** Do not redirect this into `> foo` again as you could end up with an empty file.

Comment: +1. It works. For future reference, "foo" is the filename. To output to file, I just redirected it to a new file with this command: "(cat foo; echo) | tac -s $'\n\n' | sed '$d' > foo1.txt".

Answer (score 2):

Although the author doesn't prefer programming solutions, using Python would be fairly easy in 1 line:

```
open('output.txt', 'w').write('\n\n'.join(reversed(open('input.txt', 'r').read().split('\n\n'))))
```

Obviously replace `input.txt` and `output.txt` with the desired files, and change `\n` to `\r\n` for Windows-formatted text files.

Put this in a `.py` file and call it via `python myscript.py`.

Comment: +1, I like the one-liner. Python really allows some cool stuff

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows then you could simply use Powershell. This reverses the contents of `test.txt` and saves the result to `test2.txt`:

```
$f=Get-Content c:\folder\test.txt
[array]::Reverse($f)
$f | out-file c:\folder\test2.txt
```

**Update:**

This should do the trick (reads all the lines from `test.txt` and rearranges them to `test2.txt` file the way you wanted):

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines("C:\Folder\test.txt")
$a = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$i=0
ForEach ($line in $content) {If ($line -ne "") {$a.insert($i++, $line)} else {$a.insert(0, $line); $i=0}}
$a | out-file C:\Folder\test2.txt
```

Probably not the most elegant way but it did the job with your test case.

Comment: Unfortunately, the command also reverses the order of the individual lines within the text sections, which is not what I want. For example, the order for "A, B" becomes "B, A", where the comma and space are a newline.

Comment: @XP1: I assume therefore this is Windows ?

Comment: @BigChief, I am on Windows Vista, but I will accept solutions for either Windows or GNU/Linux-based OSes. Even though I said that I prefer a solution without programming, I will accept programming as long as the solution is simple (for example, a one-liner or a couple lines).

Comment: @XP1: sorry, misread the original question yesterday.